# How to prevent memoizedCall() of R.cache package from updating cache every time source file is modified?

Tags: r, memoization

I am trying to use memoizedCall() of R.cache package to cache calls to my function that loads large amount of data from a remote server and takes long time to run every time. This works as long as I do not edit the source file from where memoizedCall() is called (the function to be memoized is in the same source file, in case this is important). This does not work for me because my use case for caching is that I want to load data once and then edit/save/rerun functions that use this data.

I know that the loadCache() function, which is called by memoizedCall(), has argument removeOldCache (decription: If TRUE and the cache is older than the sources, the cache file is removed, otherwise not). This seems to be what I need, but memoizedCall does not accept this argument.

Answer (score 0):

evalWithMemoization() from the same package worked for me. Unlike memoizedCall, it takes all the arguments loadCache() takes, but I actually did not need to specify any arguments for it to keep using cache after source file had been modified.